# JavaScript send out an alert to prompt and edit array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, prompt

```
//global variable
var memArray  =[];

//object    
function member(id, password){

  this.id          = id; 
  this.pwd         = password
  }
  var memObj1=new member("m001","123");
  memArray.push(memObj1);
```

How do I send out an alert to prompt and edit each object that is push to memArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to customize it try to use your own modals instead of window.prompt and just display values with editable text fields, on submit capture those values and change them in array respectively.

```js
var memArray = [];


//object    
function member(id, password) {

  this.id = id;
  this.pwd = password
}
var memObj1 = new member("m001", "123");
var memObj2 = new member("m002", "123");
var memObj3 = new member("m031", "123");
memArray.push(memObj1);
memArray.push(memObj2);
memArray.push(memObj3);
memArray.forEach((val, ind) => {
  memArray[ind] = JSON.parse(window.prompt("want to edit values?", JSON.stringify(memArray[ind])));
});

console.log(memArray)
```

Comment: here to help anytime @fendi. Happy coding.

Comment: Good solution. One suggestion: use `Array.map` and return a new array, rather than mutating. Mutation increases complexity and bugs. See [this article](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/just-say-no-to-loops-and-variables/).

Comment: @JoshWulf I agree on the point you mentioned, I was trying to give simple solution, also I mentioned about having a custom modal pop-up instead of window.prompt. thanks for the update.

Comment: Oh yeah, your solution is good, and it answers the immediate question that the user had. My suggestion is more of an improvement to something that is already fine. No shade :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pavan's answer is good, but to make this testable in automated tests:

```js
// I would name these fields in your API 
// by making the constructor take an object.
// Capitalise the name to signal that it can be newed    
function Member({id, password}) {
  this.id = id;
  this.pwd = password
}

// Name the array for what it is
const members = [ 
  new Member({id: "m001", password: "123"}),
  new Member({id: "m002", password: "123"}),
  new Member({id: "m031", password: "123"})
]

const editInBrowserFn = member => JSON.parse(window.prompt("want to edit values?", JSON.stringify(member)));

const updateMembers = editFn => array => array.map(editFn)

// To get an update
const updatedMembers = updateMembers(editInBrowserFn)(members)

console.log(updatedMembers)

// You can now test it by making an testing editFn that doesn't need user interaction

const testEditFn = m => new Member({id: m.id, password: 'test'})

const testMembers = updateMembers(testEditFn)(members)
console.log(testMembers)
```

See [this article](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/just-say-no-to-loops-and-variables/) for an in-depth explanation of this approach.

To do it this way, you will need to take it out of the global scope. That is a good discipline to develop. As a first step you could make an object in global scope that holds the latest member list:

```
const Members = (() => {
   let _members = []
   return {
      setMembers: members => _members = [...members],
      getMembers: () => [..._members]
   }
})()
```

Now the way to update the members is like this:

```
const updateFn = updateMembers(editInBrowser)

function updatePasswords() {
   const members = Members.getMembers()
   Members.setMembers(updateFn(members))
}
```

Nothing can accidentally delete or mutate the members array now, so that bug surface area is eliminated.

This is how React `setState` is designed. It's inspired by functional programming ideas and immutability.

You probably want to be able to update just one member, so:

```
const Members = (() => {
   let _members = []
   return {
      setMembers: members => _members = [...members],
      getMembers: () => [..._members],
      updateMember: updated => 
         this.members = _members.map(m =>
            m.id === updated.id ? updated : m)
   }
})()
```

Now all your array mutation is in one single place, and you only have to make it bug-free there. Otherwise, your global state is exposed and you have to fix bugs everywhere related to it. Without this, all your calling functions are responsibly for correctly managing the global state of the application. Complex.

Crystallise the complexity in one place.

I wrote an article and a complete implementation of the store (in 40 lines of code) [here](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/avoid-global-state/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I concern, alerts are just models on the browser to provide informative feedback to a particular user on his actions. Therefore, I think it is required to use either a dialog model or a form to edit the objects in the `memArray`.

Comment: Please try adding a code snippet for the OP to understand.